# Asset validation failed due to libswiftcoregraphics.dylib while uploading Xamarin ipa to App Centre on mac

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

When I try to pass validation in xcode while uploading my .ipa to App Centre I get error:
**Ivalid bundle structure, the "*appname.ios*/SwiftFrameworkSimulator/libswiftcoregraphics.dylib" binary file is not permitted.** Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries.

I tried to manually remove libswiftcoregraphics.dylib from package, after that I successfully uploaded build, but got another error by email: **ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.**